# How to calculate the differences between the adjacent elements from two vectors?

Tags: difference, dolphindb, array-difference, difference-between-rows

I want to calculate the differences between of the Nth value of the vector X and the N-1th value of the vector Y. All I know is the function `delta`, but it can only work within one vector. Does anyone know a better method? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`deltas(X)` is equivalent to `X - prev(X)`. So you can do `X - prev(Y)` for your requirement.